# How to delete a native image?

Tags: .net

I am not able to delete a native image :

```
del c:\windows\assembly\native...\mscorlib\xxxx\mscorlib.ni.dll
access refused
```

That works on Windows XP, but not in Seven.

Does someone know how can I do ?

Comment: If you're trying to delete something in use by IIS or otherwise, make sure you stop the other process first or you will probably receive this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen this type of behavior before when the file is in use.  Get Process Explorer (sysinternals) and do a "find handle or dll" search for the filename.  You'll have to kill any process that is using the image.

Comment: Used by MOM.exe and CCC.exe


Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are probably trying that from a non-elevated command prompt.

However, instead of accessing the GAC from the file system you should use the tools provided by the .NET Framework. A native image can be removed by a call to `ngen.exe` with the approriate switches (call `ngen.exe /?` to get help):

> ```
> ngen uninstall <assembly name> [scenarios] [config]
>     Delete the native images of an assembly and its dependencies from
>     the Native Images Cache.
> ```

Anyway, you are trying to delete the native image of mscorlib. Is there any particular reason you want to remove this image? This looks like asking for trouble to me.

Comment: I have run with cmd.exe as Administrator, and It is the same problem.

I have told mscorlib.ni.dll just for example.